# How to implement JWT on Gluon Mobile apps

Tags: gluon-mobile

I am trying to develop iOS and Android apps using Gluon Mobile. The apps will have login and I have used JWT approach to login on the server so every request made from the app needs to include JWT token. Now, my question, since this may be platform specific, is how to store and retrieve from storage this token to be used on each requst.

Comment: For anything related to storage, see the Charm Down [Storage Service](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html).

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: Working as advertised, many thanks.